# parent ng-class on 2 children ng-click angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class

I'm trying to change parent class name with different child ng-click
here is code:

```
<div class="item"
             ng-class="{'_first': isFirst, '_second': isSecond}"
             ng-repeat="item in currentCtrl.currentData">
 <div class="btn-container">
                <button class="btn"
                        ng-click="isFirst = !isFirst">first</button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-container">
                <button class="btn"
                        ng-click="isSecond = !isSecond">second</button>
            </div>
</div>
```

it's working for first only
what I missed?

**EDITED:**
found trouble, code is correct

Comment: You have a CSS class defined for `_first` and `_second`?  Does `isSecond` work and stay like that when you click it first?

Comment: @jcc the trouble is, `isFirst` works, it's add class to item, `isSecond` not, I don't understand this problem

Comment: I'm asking if that, when you first load up the page, if you click on `isSecond` first, does it work?  I'm thinking your `ng-click` expressions are not turning the other property off and thus creating a conflict that results in nothing happening.

Comment: @jcc sorry, didn't catch you message, there isn't any result

Comment: Did you figure it out? What was the solution?

Answer (score 1):

do you have like this?

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
  
  $scope.items = [1,2,3,4];
  $scope.isSecond = true;
  $scope.isFirst = false;
 
    
   
  })
```

```css
._first{
  color:red;
  }

._second{
 color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

       <div class="item" ng-class="isFirst== true ? '_first' : '_second'"
         ng-repeat="item in items">
         <p> this is a test</p>
             <div class="btn-container">
                <button class="btn"
                        ng-click="isFirst= !isFirst">first</button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-container">
                <button class="btn"
                        ng-click="isFirst = !isFirst">second</button>
            </div>
        </div>
  
 </div>
```